# Get 2 strings from a string - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am new to the PHP, need to get "url" and "description" from following string.

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhnVcAC5bIM">Official: Desi Kalakaar Full VIDEO Song | Yo Yo Honey Singh | Honey Singh New Songs 2014</a>
```

Any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to go about it would be to use the [`SimpleXMLElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class:

```
$str = '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhnVcAC5bIM">Official: Desi Kalakaar Full VIDEO Song | Yo Yo Honey Singh | Honey Singh New Songs 2014</a>';

$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

$url = $elem->attributes();
$url = $url["href"];

$description = $elem->__toString(); // or just $elem.

echo "URL: " . $url;
echo "<br>";
echo "Description: " . $description;
```

Comment: Throwing syntax error near $url = $elem->attributes()["href"];
Error = syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @user3820288 That means you're using an older version of PHP. Try the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>
```

You can try this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nC8jC7/1